# Silverlight - Show BusyIndicator on busy UI Thread

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

It is possible to show the Busy Indicator when a heavy task is occurring in the UI? In our app majority of the long running task are rendering controls and we need to show an indicator while this controls are rendering.

Comment: check this http://forums.silverlight.net/post/556179.aspx

Comment: Thanks, already checked that :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show a loading animation while the UI thread is busy, but you can show a static notification like a `TextBlock` control with appropriate text. But if you start the long running operation on the UI thread right after updating the text of the `TextBlock` control, then the UI of the control will not get updated till the operation ends. To overcome this problem you can use the technique described in the answer of the following question: [Showing a text indicator before freezing the Silverlight UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931032/showing-a-text-indicator-before-freezing-the-silverlight-ui-thread/15936058?noredirect=1#comment22841992_15936058).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, look into using a background thread to do the long-running work. If this is not possible, i.e. its genuinely taking ages to load UI components on the UI thread, then you can certainly place a busy indicator as an overlay on top of the loading parts and then hide the overlay when everything is loaded.

By the way, its hard to write a responsive, multi-threaded app without separating your UI logic from your UI. Research the 'MVVM' pattern. Using MVVM will bring your apps on leaps and bounds.

I'd say that no serious app uses 'code behind', i.e. everything is done via a DataContext, data-binding, ViewModels and Commands.

Otherwise, look into using Tasks or the BackgroundWorker and understand the Dispatcher.

Luke

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DispatcherTimer to set the busy indicator running before the heavy task is called (by using a delay).

Then you can disable the indicator once the heavy task is complete.

Works for me.

```
'enable busy indicator & set up the timer'
 Private Sub renderControl(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)

        _busyIndicator.IsBusy = True

        Dim timer As New DispatcherTimer
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)
        AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf renderControl_TimerTick
        timer.Start()

    End Sub

'do your heavy task, disable busy indicator then stop the timer'
  Private Sub renderControl_TimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        DoStuff()

        _busyIndicator.IsBusy = False

        'Stop the timer'
        TryCast(sender, DispatcherTimer).[Stop]() 

    End Sub
```

Hope this helps!