# Showing a text indicator before freezing the Silverlight UI thread

Tags: silverlight, ui-thread

At some point in my Silverlight application I need to perform a heavy operation which freezes the UI thread for about 4 seconds. Before actually performing the operation I am trying to display a simple text indicator via a `TextBlock` control.

```
StatusTextBlock.Text = "Performing Some Operation...";
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000); // Just as an example
```

The problem is that the UI thread freezes before the text of the `TextBlock` control gets updated. How can I get the notification text shown before the operation begins?

Also, taking the heavy operation to a background thread is not an option for me, as it deals with UI objects (it switches the visual root of the application) and should be executed on the UI thread.

Comment: Is using a background thread not possible? its always good to take long running operations off the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't use a background thread. Please take a look at the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with the help of Jeff Prosise's blog post: http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jprosise/archive/2008/10/25/cool-silverlight-trick-5.aspx

The idea is to delay the call performing a long running task till a Silverlight UI rendering event fires. For this I used the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event. I subscribed to it in the constructor of the user control:

```
CompositionTarget.Rendering += this.CompositionTargetRendering;
```

After I update the text of a `TextBlock` control I set a private flag, which indicates that some processing should be made in the event handler:

```
StatusTextBlock.Text = "Performing Some Operation...";
this.processRenderingEvent = true;
```

And here is the code of the handler:

```
private void CompositionTargetRendering(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.processRenderingEvent)
    {
        if (++this.renderingEventCounter == 2)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000); // Example of long running task
            this.processRenderingEvent = false;
        }
    }
}
```

An important point to mention here is that I use a private integer field `renderingEventCounter` to begin the long running task not the first time the event fires, but the second. The reason for this is that the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event is fired just before the Silverlight UI rendering engine draws a new frame on the application's display surface, which means that at the first time the event fires the text of the `TextBlock` control is not yet updated. But it will be updated the second time.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to take it off UI thread and use background thread...

```
StatusTextBox.Text = "Before Sleep";
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
bw.RunWorkerAsync();

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);}


void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    StatusTextBox.Text = "after Sleep";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but using a background thread is not an option for me, as the operation is dealing with UI objects and should be executed on the UI thread (I have edited my question).

Comment: Yea, I have no idea how to do what you are achieving (since bg worker is not an option) so I'll thumb's up your question... Im curious myself how you can get it working. Ill leave my answer in case it helps someone else where they can use a bg worker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement the BackgroundWorker thread is tsiom's answer, but use the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to operate on the UI objects, here is a MSDN article on how to use the method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Also, see another StackOverflow question for a more comprehensive scenario using the Dispatcher: [Understanding the Silverlight Dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581647/understanding-the-silverlight-dispatcher)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have read an article about how to wait for the UI rendering to finish using Dispatcher in WCF (http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/08/29/update-my-ui-now-how-to-wait-for-the-rendering-to-finish/). This is done by assigning DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle priority to the action performed by the Dispatcher, which is lower than the priority of UI rendering. But unfortunately Silverlight doesn't support DispatcherPriority, so I'm not sure if Dispatcher can help in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this situation myself. The problem (I think) is that before the text gets updated you have already begun the intensive operation, so you have to wait.

What you can do is to attach a listened to some method on the textbox that only gets called once the text is updated (textChanged perhaps?) and THEN call your intensive operation.

This seems hackish to me though...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the solution you suggested, but unfortunately to no avail. I tried using all types of events that came to my mind like TextChanged of a TextBox control, LayoutUpdated of FrameworkElement, etc. But it turns out that during the execution of handlers of these events the UI is not yet updated.

Comment: it is getting updated eventually though, right? assuming you don't try to do the intensive process, right? I'm sure it is, but it's always good to do a sanity check

Comment: It gets updated only after the intensive process finishes, which is not what I want (not sure if I answered your question).

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly but it works. By delaying the initiliazation of the long running operation using a DispatcherTimer we can allow the UI to be updated before the operation is started.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication13.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="White">

        <StackPanel>

            <Border x:Name="Brd01"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Background="Red">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="30">Sleeping for 4 seconds...</TextBlock>
            </Border>

            <Border x:Name="Brd02"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Background="Lime">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="30">Done!</TextBlock>
            </Border>

            <Button Content="Start Operation"
                    Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace SilverlightApplication13
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Show the "working..." message
            Brd01.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            //Initialize a timer with a delay of 0.1 seconds
            var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Start the long running operation
            Thread.Sleep(4000);

            Brd01.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            Brd02.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            //Kill the timer so it will only run once. 
            (sender as DispatcherTimer).Stop();
            (sender as DispatcherTimer).Tick -= Timer_Tick;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was also thinking of some workaround like this, but that's not a robust solution as you also have mentioned. Anyways, thanks for your effort.

Comment: You are right, it is not pretty. But with all UI programming I keep finding myself in situations like this where an ugly workaround is unavoidable. If you absolutely must show a "working..." message in your situation (where you cannot use a background thread) this is the only way I can think of.